# Getting ClassNotFoundException in Grails 2.5.6

Tags: grails

Migrating from 1.3.7 to 2.5.6
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.project.compiler.GrailsProjectCompiler how can we fix this?
Trying to build project using goal grails:clean grails:war -Dmaven.skip.test=true
Grails Version : 2.5.6
Java version 1.7

Comment: trying to migrate from 1.3.7 to 2.5.6

Comment: How do you trigger that error? And please: add all relevant information to the question, not to the comment section

Comment: Note that you can't just "compile the project" with a newer Grails.  There are certainly project structure changes from 1.3.x to 2.5.x, as well as package changes, etc.   I suggest starting with a new Grails 2.5.x project, and migrating the code from your old project some classes at a time.

Answer (score 0):

As stated by the comments, you're in for quite a ride to get this up and running.

This particular error is probably because you are missing the new dependencies needed for Grails. This is what you need if you have a maven project which I assume you have while getting this problem:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.grails</groupId>
        <artifactId>grails-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>${grails.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.grails</groupId>
        <artifactId>grails-test</artifactId>
        <version>${grails.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.grails</groupId>
        <artifactId>grails-plugin-testing</artifactId>
        <version>${grails.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

You also have to remove all of the old dependencies to the 1.3 grails core. In 1.3 it was a series of dependencies if I don't remember incorrectly.

If it is not a maven project you should get this for free by specifying the `inerits("global")` in your BuildConfig.groovy:

```
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
   // inherit Grails' default dependencies
   inherits("global") {
       // specify dependency exclusions here; for example, uncomment this to     
   }
...
```

That said, this will not be the last of your problems while upgrading. I have successfully managed to upgrade some small projects but it has taken quite an effort. For larger projects, I would seriously consider if it is worth it.

My best advice if you decide to go through with it is to generate a new empty 2.5.6 project and compare settings and dependencies to your legacy project.